# Set value for same cell in "DevExpress XtraGrid CellValueChanging" event

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress

I have a XtraGrid with one GridView, with a column with checkbox repository item. Now I am handling the CellValueChanging event because I want to only allow the user to check or uncheck based on calculations on other column values on the same row hence I need the `e.RowHandle` and `e.Column` of this event and this cannot be done on the EditValueChanging of the repository control.

Now somewhere my calculations say that user cannot check a particular cell to and I throw a message box and try `Me.BandedGridView1.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, e.Column, False)` but unfortunately this does not set the value to false of that cell.

I need to do it here and here only because of the huge number of calculations based on other column values and I need to set value of the current cell whose event I'm handling right.

Please help.

I'm using DevExpress 9.2 (no chance of upgrading to higher version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to prevent updates by handling ShowingEditor event.

```
class TestData
{
    public TestData(string caption, bool check)
    {
        Caption = caption;
        Check = check;
    }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public bool Check { get; set; }
}
```

Initialize some test data:

```
BindingList<TestData> gridDataList = new BindingList<TestData>();
gridDataList.Add(new TestData("First row", true));
gridDataList.Add(new TestData("Second row", true));
gridControl.DataSource = gridDataList;
```

Handle ShowingEditor. Check if user is allowed to change chechbox. If not, cancel the event.

```
    private void gridView1_ShowingEditor(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        //  Decision to allow edit using view.FocusedRowHandle and view.FocusedColumn
        if (view.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "Check")
        {
            //  Allow edit of odd rows only
            bool allowEdit = view.FocusedRowHandle % 2 == 1;
            e.Cancel = !allowEdit;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code it's working perfectly !

```
private void GridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Caption != "yourColumnCaption") return;
       GridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("yourColumnFieldName", 1);
}
```